# URLConnection Basic Authorization with hashed password

Tags: java, sha1, urlconnection

I want to open URLConnection to a page that use 'Basic' authentication (Digest method = SHA1).

I only have the hashed password, how can I open the connection?

Answer (score 0):

If the password is hashed using the same algorithm as the HTTP authorization scheme just send the hashed password. If it’s hashed with a different algorithm you’re out of luck.

Comment: It is hashed with the same algorithm, but when I just pass the hashed password I'm getting authentication error.

Comment: Yes, for basic authorization you need the password in cleartext. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication for details.